# "X is an evident part of Y" versus "X is evidently a part of Y"

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives, adverbs

How are the two sentences different?

```
1. X is an evident part of Y.
2. X is evidently a part of Y.
```

Can anybody shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sentence 1 means that X is a prominent and readily discernible part of Y.

Sentence 2 means that X turns out to be a part of Y- Who knew!?